# Is there any wat to create Mac explorer-like-dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown that functions same like mac explorer. vertical navbar and sub menus on right side. I can only make vertical navbar but sub menus are also opening vertically.

Sorry to say this, but i got nothing. I know I have to show my input but I have nothing this time. 
Atleast give me a start.

Comment: By "mac explorer", do you mean the Finder?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes.